# Mouse in-out events for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

question from a beginner..

I want to show/hide an inner div when the mouse enter/out from the parent div. I tried first with `onmouseover`, `onmouseout` events, but the problem is that `onmouseover` keep firing while the mouse over the div, and I want it to fire one time only.

I found [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) events that might help me, but I don't know where can I put this code because my divs exist in a template for a control, and there is no `onload` event for the div.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Where should I call this !!!
    function Init(sender) {
        $(sender).bind("mouseenter", function () {
            $(sender.childNodes[1], this).show(500);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $(sender.childNodes[1], this).hide(500);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Any help!

Comment: Please post the code you have. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for everybody. as YNhat [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337216/mouse-in-out-events-for-javascript/5337299#5337299), I have to use classes instead of Ids. and this is the code that I used and it's work well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitEntities();
});

function InitEntities() {
    var parentDiv = $(".parentDivClass");

    parentDiv.each(function (index) {
        var childDiv = $(this).children(".childDivClass");    
        $(this).bind("mouseenter", function () {
            $(childDiv, this).show(250);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $(childDiv, this).hide(250);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave) events.

You can put your code in the  and bind your  with these events.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
        Init('.your_div_class');
    });

    function Init(sender) {
        $(sender).bind("mouseenter", function () {
            $(sender.childNodes[1], this).show(500);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $(sender.childNodes[1], this).hide(500);
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that my divs exist inside a template. so I don't have the `Id`

Comment: Do you have class or anything you think you can use to identify the div? Maybe I need to take a look at your html structure

Comment: Yes, I think this is what should I do. using classes instead of `IDs`

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.parent_div .inner_div
{
 display:none;
}

.parent_div:hover .inner_div
{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to use animation, so I've gone to JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in a script.

Once the document is fully loaded (`$(document).ready`) the mouseover event is bound.

I then unbind the event when I'm in it (to prevent it from spamming the event) and bind the mouseleave event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#loginformwrapper").bind("mouseover", showLoginForm);

});

function showLoginForm() {
    $("#loginformwrapper").unbind("mouseover", showLoginForm);
    $("#loginform").animate({
        top: '+=80'
      }, 1000, function() {
          $("#loginform").bind("mouseleave", hideLoginForm);
      });
}

function hideLoginForm() {
    $("#loginform").unbind("mouseleave", hideLoginForm);
    $("#loginform").animate({
        top: '-=80'
      }, 1000, function() {
          $("#loginformwrapper").bind("mouseover", showLoginForm);
      });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that my divs exist inside a template. so I don't have the `Id`

Comment: Isn't it possible to add an id when you render the template?

Comment: @iarwain01: No, it's auto-generated. because many instances will be created.

Comment: I don't know how to help if there is no id.

Comment: Thanks, seems I found it. I'll use Classes instead.

Comment: Great! Please post your answer when you found it and accept it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        var mydiv = $("#parent_div_id");
        $(mydiv).bind("mouseenter", function () {
            $(mydiv.childNodes[1], this).show(500);
        }).bind("mouseleave", function () {
            $(mydiv.childNodes[1], this).hide(500);
        });
    });
</script>
```

replace the "parent_div_id" with the id of your parent div

Comment: The problem is that my divs exist inside a template. so I don't have the `Id`